# User customizable Template

Tags: django, django-templates

So I have a template to render a PDF and I want to be able to customize this PDF. But in this text some dynamic information is added so I want to do the following thing:

In a `model.TextField` I want to set a string like `string = 'Text {{ count }} Text text'` and than I want to render this string in my template like so:

```
<p>
{{ string }}
</p>
```

How can I get this so that the template engine renders it like this:

```
<p>
Text {{ count }} Text text
</p>
```

Comment: try `django-weasyprint`.  You can then just use normal django templates

Comment: iam already using weasyprint. the problem is not the PDF its that i want to be able to define a part of the template in a model

Comment: then just use a property

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def my_textfield(self):
        # you'll need to define count somewhere
        return f'Text { count } Text text'
```